# Remap Camera Control in Guild Wars

Tags: guild-wars

I've just installed Guild Wars on my brand new MacBook, but I've run into an issue with the camera control.  The default controls are set so that you hold down the right mouse button and move the mouse to move the camera.  However, I am unable to get that to work with the fancy trackpad on the MacBook.  (I can right-click in Windows, so I know the click works, but it doesn't work in Guild Wars.)

Is there a way to remap the camera control to a different button, so that I can play Guild Wars without hooking up an external mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [answer to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7584/borderlands-how-can-i-get-mouse-wheel-scrolling-to-work-in-game-dialogs/7586#7586), I was successfully able to use AutoHotKey to map the mouse right-click to a key on the keyboard, which gives me the ability to control the camera in the game.

(However, I have also asked a [new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/does-key-remapping-software-violate-the-guild-wars-terms-of-service), regarding whether or not using software like AutoHotKey violates the Guild Wars Terms of Service.)