# Borderlands: How can I get mouse wheel scrolling to work in game dialogs?

Tags: borderlands

To me the most annoying thing is that the game doesn't respect the simplest UI gesture: scrolling up/down with the wheel in dialogs; only the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys work.

Is there any way to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround I found:

I'm using a Razer DeathAdder mouse and I've the software driver installed. This lets me define various mouse profiles and also lets me remap certain keys.

This is what I did: used one of my unused profiles, mapping **mouse wheel up** to <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and **mouse wheel down** to <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and changed the in game mappings accordingly.

Now I can use the wheel in-game for switching weapons *and* in the UI dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind mouse-up/down to PgUp/Down (for individual programs) with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), but it requires a bit of scripting (I'm afraid I can't help you with that).