# Does key remapping software violate the Guild Wars Terms of Service?

Tags: guild-wars

I have successfully solved the [camera issue from this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/remap-camera-control-in-guild-wars) by using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap a key to the right mouse button.

However, after I tested the solution, I realized that using key remapping software in an online game could be seen as hacking or cheating.  I took a quick look through the Guild Wars website, but did not find anything directly relating to key remapping software.

Does anyone know if I will run into problems with my account if I continue to play with AutoHotKey remapping the right mouse click to a single keypress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Software that shows additional in-game overlays, things mainly depend on what you actually do with AHK. FRAPS shows an overlay with a framerate counter, Steam shows an overlay with friends/achievements notifications and fps aimbots show an overlay showing enemies' positions, locking status and whether you are in view or not.

If your game has a button mashing portion and you use AHK to automate this, you are probably cheating. If you are merely controlling your camera, chances are you're instead in the right.

That said, rule 22 of the [Rules of Conduct](http://www.guildwars.com/support/legal/rulesofconduct.php) seems to be most relevant here. I don't think it applies here, but if you wanted to be 100 percent sure you would've asked a lawyer, not gamers.

Also related is point 7 of the [User Agreement](http://www.guildwars.com/support/legal/user-agreement.php):

> You agree not to use any hardware or software, including but not limited to third party tools, or any other method of support which may in any way influence or advantage your use of the Service which is not authorized by NC Interactive, including but not limited to the use of 'bots' and/or any other method by which the Service may be played automatically without human input.

In *spirit*, it's all against farming. In reality, you'll have to ask a lawyer.

---

I've now read the original question. If they suspend you because of *that*, I have a new entry for my blacklist.

Comment: link that rule and you've got +1 from me...

Comment: @Shader, I wrote the original reply from my mobile, sorry :)